# IOS not Showing Done Button on TMPro Integer Keyboard in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

there I am making the IOS & Android game in which I need Integer key board to enter the Amount, Only in the Integer Value.
The keyboard works fine in the Android but in the IOs it is not Showing the Done Button. I have Also Attached the Image for the Reference.

Is there Any way to do it, Any help will be Appreciated.
Thanks.[image]